# PHP - parse html files

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to parse some html files, the problem is the structure of this html is full of tag I don't care and I don't have specification of what I will find.

I want to get all `<p>` tag directly under a `<body>` tag, excluding other child nodes of `<body>` and read child nodes of `<p>` if any (with some exception I can manage excluding some specific tag)

for example:

```
<body>
  <node1>
    <p></p>
  <node1>
  <p></p>
  <p>
    <a>
    </a>
  <p>
</body>
```

I wan to exclude `node1` and its child nodes, get all other nodes
Actually my code is:

```
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body");
foreach($body as $node) {    
    if($node->childNodes->length) {    
    foreach($node->childNodes as $n) {  
        //insert here check: if nodeName != 'p'    
        $text .= $n->nodeName;   
     }    
   }   
}
```

I would iterate throught each childnodes and check for nodesName

How can I exclude child nodes of body different from `p` inside the first query? I tried with `$dom->getElementsByTagName("body/p");` but it doesn't work
Is there a better way to manage and query my HTML files?
thanks

Comment: Do you mind solve it by `jquery` or just clean javascript?

Comment: @Bandon Neither, considering the question is about PHP.

Comment: you should look into [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) also

Comment: I would do this with xslt

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way to do it but it could do the job for someone:

```
<?php
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>
  <node1>
    <p>1</p>
  <node1>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3
    <a>
    </a>
  <p>
</body>     
</html>
";      

$doc = new DOMDocument;
// our HTML might not be perfectly valid so we don't want to be warned about it
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

// Count all p tags first
$ptagscntr = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
// if we have p tags
if ($ptagscntr->length) {
    // iterate
    for ($i=0;$i<$ptagscntr->length;$i++)  {
        // get each node
        var_dump($doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item($i));
        echo '<br>----<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use similar code to clean up user script snippets from articles they post with their contents, so it may help, just replace the tags in array with yours. Result will be html without the tags you specified as well as with their descends

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// $body is your html you load into this variable elsewhere
// Note that there will be a warning if any invalid tags like
// node1 will be loaded, but in most cases it will continue to work
@$dom->loadHTML($body);

$tags_to_remove = array('node1', 'node2');

// Collect and remove the tags with everything they hold.
$remove = array();

foreach ($tags_to_remove as $removal_target) {
    $sentenced = $dom->getElementsByTagName($removal_target);

    foreach ($sentenced as $item) {
        $remove[] = $item;
    }
}

foreach ($remove as $sentenced_item) {
    $sentenced_item->parentNode->removeChild($sentenced_item);
}

// Code below is used to get html without wrapping html>body and doctype
// added by DOMDocument
$body = '';

$body_node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($body_node->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
```

[Working code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f00630288ad794a4135d7435715057d078fb7efb). Notice that loading of html into dom object has error suppression operator `@` in front of it. Tough I have used it to have clean output for an example, I strongly advise against the use of it. [More here](http://derickrethans.nl/five-reasons-why-the-shutop-operator-should-be-avoided.html)